# Script create contacts in Active Directory does not work

Tags: powershell, active-directory, contacts

I am running a script in a test environment, where it works well
I run the script in a production environment, where it does not work

When starting on a domain controller, under the control of Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard or Enterprise.

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At C:\Scripts\GalSync.ps1:89 char:14
+ $targetCred - <<<< Properties targetAddress
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

89 Str **$targetCred -Properties targetAddress**

```
### --- GALSYNC.PS1 ---
#
#  Written by Carol Wapshere
#
#  Manages contacts in two domains based on mail-enabled users in the other domain.
#   - Contacts are created for new users.
#   - Contacts are deleted if the source user no longer meets the filter requirements.
#   - Contacts are updated with changed information.
#
#  NOTES:
#   - Requires RSAT roles and features installed. Ref http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/01/25/hey-scripting-

guy-january-25-2010.aspx
#   - Attribute deletions are not replicated - only attribute adds and changes.
#   - A user account is needed in each domain with permission to create contacts.
#   - The passwords for these user accounts must be stored in secure files using the command:
#       read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\scripts\filename.txt
#

### --- GLOBAL DEFINITIONS ---

$DOMAIN_1 = "192.168.50.11"
$DOMAIN_2 = "192.168.11.10"

$OU_CONTACTS_1 = "OU=Contact,OU=Selta,DC=rvsco,DC=ru"
$OU_CONTACTS_2 = "OU=Contact,OU=RVSco,DC=selta,DC=ru"

$USER_1 = "rvsadmin@rvsco.ru"
$USER_2 = "seltaroot@selta.ru"

$PWFILE_1 = "C:\scripts\rvsco.txt"
$PWFILE_2 = "C:\scripts\selta.txt"

## The following list of attributes will be copied from User to Contact
$arrAttribs = 

'displayName','company','givenName','mobile','postalAddress','postalCode','sn','st','streetAddress','telephoneNumber','title' 

,'mail','c','co','l','facsimileTelephoneNumber','physicalDeliveryOfficeName'

## The following filter is used by Get-ADObject to decide which users will have contacts.
$strSelectUsers = 'ObjectClass -eq "user" -and homeMDB -like "*" -and -not userAccountControl -bor 2 -and -not 

msExchHideFromAddressLists -eq $true -and -not displayName -eq "Administrator"'

### --- FUNCTION TO ADD, DELETE AND MODIFY CONTACTS IN TARGET DOMAIN BASED ON SOURCE USERS ---

function SyncContacts
{
  PARAM($sourceDC, $sourceUser, $sourcePWFile, $targetDC, $targetUser, $targetPWFile, $targetOU)
  END
    {
    $colUsers = @()
    $colContacts = @()
    $colAddContact = @()
    $colDelContact = @()
    $colUpdContact = @()

    $arrUserMail = @()
    $arrContactMail = @()

    write-host "Enumerating..."

    ### ENUMERATE USERS

    $password = get-content $sourcePWFile | convertto-securestring
    $sourceCred =  New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist $sourceUser,$password

    $colUsers = Get-ADObject -Filter $strSelectUsers -Properties * -Server $sourceDC -Credential $sourceCred

    if ($colUsers.Count -eq 0)
    {
        write-host "No users found in source domain!"
        break
    }

    foreach ($user in $colUsers)
    {
        $arrUserMail += $user.mail
    }

    ### ENUMERATE CONTACTS

    $password = get-content $targetPWFile | convertto-securestring
    $targetCred =  New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist $targetUser,$password

    $colContacts = Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "contact"' -searchbase $targetOU -Server $targetDC -Credential 

$targetCred -Properties targetAddress

    foreach ($contact in $colContacts)
    {
        $strAddress = $contact.targetAddress -replace "SMTP:",""
        $arrContactMail += $strAddress
    }

    ### FIND CONTACTS TO ADD AND UPDATE

    foreach ($user in $colUsers)
    {
        if ($arrContactMail -contains $user.mail)
        {
            write-host "Contact found for " $user.mail
            $colUpdContact += $user
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "No contact found for " $user.mail
            $colAddContact += $user
        }
    }

    ### FIND CONTACTS TO DELETE

    foreach ($address in $arrContactMail)
    {
        if ($arrUserMail -notcontains $address)
        {
            $colDelContact += $address
            write-host "Contact will be deleted for " $address
        }
    }

    write-host ""
    write-host "Updating ...."

    ### ADDS

    foreach ($user in $colAddContact)
    {
        write-host "ADDING contact for " $user.mail

        $targetAddress = "SMTP:" + $user.mail
        $alias = "c-" + $user.mail.split("@")[0]

        $hashAttribs = @{'targetAddress' = $targetAddress}
            $hashAttribs.add("mailNickname", $alias)

        foreach ($attrib in $arrAttribs)
        {
            if ($user.$attrib -ne $null) { $hashAttribs.add($attrib, $user.$attrib) }
        }
        New-ADObject -name $user.displayName -type contact -Path $targetOU -Description $user.description -server $targetDC 

-credential $targetCred -OtherAttributes $hashAttribs
    }

    ### UPDATES

    foreach ($user in $colUpdContact)
    {
        write-host "VERIFYING contact for " $user.mail

        $strFilter = "targetAddress -eq ""SMTP:" + $user.mail + """"
        $colContacts = Get-ADObject -Filter $strFilter -searchbase $targetOU -server $targetDC -credential $targetCred -

Properties *
        foreach ($contact in $colContacts)
        {
            $hashAttribs = @{}
            foreach ($attrib in $arrAttribs)
            {
                if ($user.$attrib -ne $null -and $user.$attrib -ne $contact.$attrib)
                {
                    write-host "    Changing " $attrib
                    write-host "        Before: " $contact.$attrib
                    write-host "        After: " $user.$attrib
                    $hashAttribs.add($attrib, $user.$attrib)
                }
            }
            if ($hashAttribs.Count -gt 0)
            {
                Set-ADObject -identity $contact -server $targetDC -credential $targetCred -Replace $hashAttribs
            }
        }

    }

    ### DELETES

    foreach ($contact in $colDelContact)
    {
        write-host "DELETING contact for " $contact
        $strFilter = "targetAddress -eq ""SMTP:" + $contact + """"
        Get-ADObject -Filter $strFilter -searchbase $targetOU -server $targetDC -credential $targetCred | Remove-ADObject -

server $targetDC -credential $targetCred -Confirm:$false
    }

  }
}

### --- MAIN ---

Start-Transcript galsync.log

if(@(get-module | where-object {$_.Name -eq "ActiveDirectory"} ).count -eq 0) {import-module ActiveDirectory}

write-host "DOMAIN1 Users --> DOMAIN2 Contacts"
SyncContacts -sourceDC $DOMAIN_1 -sourceUser $USER_1 -sourcePWFile $PWFILE_1 -targetDC $DOMAIN_2 -targetUser $USER_2 -targetPWFile 

$PWFILE_2 -targetOU $OU_CONTACTS_2

write-host ""
write-host "DOMAIN2 Users --> DOMAIN1 Contacts"
SyncContacts -sourceDC $DOMAIN_2 -sourceUser $USER_2 -sourcePWFile $PWFILE_2 -targetDC $DOMAIN_1 -targetUser $USER_1 -targetPWFile 

$PWFILE_1 -targetOU $OU_CONTACTS_1

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: the line 89 `$targetCred -Properties targetAddress` doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: The script should run without the line 89?

Comment: without the line 89 Script does not work
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At C:\Scripts\GalSync.ps1:145 char:2
+ - <<<< credential $targetCred -OtherAttributes $hashAttribs
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (-:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRec
ordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are line breaks in the middle of statements that are causing the trouble. You need to concatenate the lines.

Line 87 and 89 should be on one line only. Like this:

```
$colContacts = Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "contact"' -searchbase $targetOU -Server $targetDC -Credential $targetCred -Properties targetAddress
```

The same with line 143 and 145. They should belong together.

```
    New-ADObject -name $user.displayName -type contact -Path $targetOU -Description $user.description -server $targetDC -credential $targetCred -OtherAttributes $hashAttribs
```

Likewise with line 155 and 157 which should be

```
    $colContacts = Get-ADObject -Filter $strFilter -searchbase $targetOU -server $targetDC -credential $targetCred -Properties *
```

and line 185 and 187

```
    Get-ADObject -Filter $strFilter -searchbase $targetOU -server $targetDC -credential $targetCred | Remove-ADObject -server $targetDC -credential $targetCred -Confirm:$false
```

Line 200 and 202

SyncContacts -sourceDC $DOMAIN_1 -sourceUser $USER_1 -sourcePWFile $PWFILE_1 -targetDC $DOMAIN_2 -targetUser $USER_2 -targetPWFile $PWFILE_2 -targetOU $OU_CONTACTS_2

Line 206 and 208

SyncContacts -sourceDC $DOMAIN_2 -sourceUser $USER_2 -sourcePWFile $PWFILE_2 -targetDC $DOMAIN_1 -targetUser $USER_1 -targetPWFile $PWFILE_1 -targetOU $OU_CONTACTS_1

There might be more so you need to carefully look through the script for other invalid linebreaks

Best regards
Fridden